# Remove gap between <h1> and <p>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would I remove a gap between a h1 and p element? I've tried removing the padding and margins with no luck. I'm using the default bootstrap css. Any ideas?

```css
.section1{
 background-color: bisque;
}

p, h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
       <h1 class="page-header">About</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, explicabo dolores ipsam aliquam inventore corrupti eveniet quisquam quod totam laudantium repudiandae obcaecati ea consectetur debitis velit facere nisi expedita vel?</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've attached a screenshot to this post as it appears correctly when I run the code using stackoverflows 'run snippet' feature.
[image]

Comment: Do you have another stylesheet loading in?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm going to guess that bootstrap.css is adding margin to the h1 because of the class `page-header`. This will override your `h1` in your stylesheet because it is more specific. Change your custom.css to `h1.page-header` and see what happens.

Comment: Read up on CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

The `page-header` bootstrap class is causing the *space* reset it using:

```
h1.page-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.section1 {
  background-color: bisque;
}
p,
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1.page-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, explicabo dolores ipsam aliquam inventore corrupti eveniet quisquam quod totam laudantium repudiandae obcaecati ea consectetur debitis velit facere nisi expedita vel?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height` to h1 class in your CSS. If font size is 26px, just ad 26px line height.

like:

```
h1.page-header{
font-size:26px;
line-height:26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height` to it

```css
.section1 {
  background-color: bisque;
  line-height: 15px;
}
p,
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.page-header{
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, explicabo dolores ipsam aliquam inventore corrupti eveniet quisquam quod totam laudantium repudiandae obcaecati ea consectetur debitis velit facere nisi expedita vel?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are writing h1 and p element consecutively and not have image element in between. this was the issue for me. other than that removing the bottom margin from h1 and top margin from p should solve your problem. cheers

Answer (score -3):

You need to reset css first. Because Browser has format CSS itself

- {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;}

Add this above your css file